# Why BroadcastReceiver for checking battery status not work without registerReceiver() method to register him?

Tags: android

I have this code for the BroadcastReceiver

```
public class BatteryBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        int level = intent.getIntExtra("level", 0);
        MDIS.info("Battery Level: " + level + "%");
    }
}
```

And this is my manifest section

```
<receiver android:name=".BroadcastReceivers.BatteryBroadcastReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Why i should use the registerReceiver() method if i add necessary lines in manifest file?

Comment: I write this xml code section only once.

Comment: You didn't write anything twice. Your question already has an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9123305/436938

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the official doc for getting battery status [**here**](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html)

From official doc:

> Because it's a sticky intent, you don't need to register a
>   BroadcastReceiver

So if you want to get the current state of battery just do this:

```
IntentFilter ifilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
Intent batteryStatus = context.registerReceiver(null, ifilter);
int level = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
int scale = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
float batteryPct = level / (float)scale;
//the variable 'batteryPct ' represents the % of battery
```

### Low Battery

To know where the battery is low edit your manifest like this:

```
<receiver android:name=".BroadcastReceivers.BatteryBroadcastReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.android.intent.action.BATTERY_LOW"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And you will be able to catch the broadcast when fired

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged on SO. Please post explanation  here, otherwise, your answer is subjected to close reason "Not an Answer".

Comment: Ok I'll edit it right away @DroidDev

Comment: I read this doc, but there's no explain to my question.

Comment: @G043B Updated, have a look

Comment: Can i use this code to catch the low battery state, if yes, then what modification i must do?

Comment: You want to know when you are in low battery? @G043B

Comment: @G043B I updated the answer, have a look :)!

Comment: I make an application that monitoring my phone and send some information to my PC. I think in this case i must create that BroadcastReceiver and catch this battery low event to send this information to my PC. This is the concept of what i need. @Assa

Comment: @G043B I have already updated the answer, have a look. You need to change your manifest, and you are almost done

Comment: @G043B Can you please update us? Have you encountred any other problem?

Answer (score 0):

> Why i should use the registerReceiver() method if i add necessary lines in manifest file?

Some broadcasts, such as `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED`, are limited to receivers registered via `registerReceiver()`. These are broadcasts for which Google did not want to have to fork a bunch of processes to go deliver, either due to the frequency of the broadcast or the timing of the broadcast.